# Как сделать счётчик тактов процесса

Tags: c++, процесс, cpu

Например есть условно какой-то **процесс номер 1**, он выполняется как и все остальные процессы в системе параллельно другим, как можно получить количество тактов, которое использовал процесс номер 1?  Вот пожалуйста схема для более лучшего понимания вопроса:
[image: схема]
Мне нужно измерить количество тактов именно **процесса номер 1** и никакого другого. На данном отрезке количество тактов процесса 1 равно четырем, количество тактов процесса номер 2 равно 5 и тд
**Язык:** С++ (если реализация на С++ невозможна то подскажите где это можно тогда сделать)

Comment: Тут важен не язык, а ОС. Только у нее есть вся необходимая информация.

Comment: @gbg, Windows по-классике

Comment: Нужно использовать счётчики производительности: [Performance Counters](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/perfctrs/performance-counters-portal)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если в windows, то используйте GetThreadTimes

https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-getthreadtimes?redirectedfrom=MSDN